# Get string message from catch error in do/try/catch with Swift

Tags: swift, try-catch

I have 2 classes, 1 is where view controller of form and the other is custom class to validate all forms in my app.

In the enum of the list of possible errors I have these:

```
enum ValidateErrors: ErrorType{

case Empty(desc: String)
case WrongFormat(desc: String)

}
```

and inside the validate method from the same class I have these:

```
guard email.characters.count > 0 else { throw ValidateErrors.Empty(desc:"Empty email.") }
```

When I do the do/try/catch in the view controller, I need to show an error message with "Empty email." but it show: Empty("Empty email.")

These is the code from the view controller where I make the do/try/catch

```
  do{

        try ValidateData.validateEmail(emailTextView.text!)
        print("Campo Valido")

    }catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to that yet?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error

And in Swift 4 try this for your example:

```
enum ValidateErrors: Error
{
    case Empty(desc: String)
    case WrongFormat(desc: String)
}
```

---

```
do
{
    try ValidateData.validateEmail(emailTextView.text!)
    print("Campo Valido")
}
catch ValidateErrors.Empty(desc: let error)
{
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You might try `print(error.desc)`

Comment: If I try these, I have a compiler error "Value of type 'ErrorType' has no member 'desc'"